# Set Width using Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net, telerik

I wish to set width of a `RadNumericTextBox` which is rendered as a input element on page using `javascript`.

I have successfully set the width but the `telerik` controls have build in javascript functions which reset the input element width on certain javascript events.

I cannot achieve this through backend as this controls are dynamically generated and the width is set for only some specfic controls.

is there anyway to maintain the width of `textbox` using javascript regardless of any events which may be fired and reset the width.

Comment: What you can try is to add your javascript method -which sets the width- as lastest as possible to the "certains" events.

Answer (score 0):

You should subscribe to the same events and change with of your Text Box after they changed it. It should be fast and your users will not see it.

Comment: its changed at almost all events.. is there any generic event that is fired in javascript on every event so that this can be updated?

Comment: You just fill list of every event separated by spaces